# Is it possible to have conditionally required YAML fields?

Tags: yaml

Our API has an endpoint with three possible parameters: A, B, C. If A and B are provided then C is optional. If either A or B is missing then C is required. Is there a way to express this conditional requirement in YAML?

Comment: YAML is a data format without much specified semantics. You can specify anything in YAML as long as the code loading the YAML supports it. You need to tell us what tool or code you use to process the YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Defined Conditions based on stage variable like mentioned below under `resources`.

```
Conditions:
    ProdEnv:
        Fn::Equals: 
        - ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
        - prod

    StagingEnv:
        Fn::Equals: 
        - ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
        - staging

    DevEnv:
        Fn::Equals: 
        - ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
        - dev
```

Mention Condition as per stage.

```
Domain:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
    Condition: ProdEnv
```

This is what you want? Please let me know how you go.